# Magento 2: I want to upload file in magento 2 from front-end

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, file-upload

$uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);

I want to know 'fileId' and 'image' what is this one mean?

Comment: Please check https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-file-upload-control-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

> Here `image` is the **input name** and also the field name of your
>   **Database table**

For More Details Check This [Tutorial](http://code.vky.co.in/magento-2-custom-module-image-upload/)